# Почему sysinfo возвращает кол-во процессов больше чем ps aux

Tags: linux, c

Почему `sysinfo` возвращает кол-во процессов (`procs`) больше чем `ps aux`

Пример функции:

```
static void
print_sysinfo()
{
 struct sysinfo info;
 sysinfo(&info);
 printf("Number of current processes - %d\n", info.procs); # На моей системе это 452
}
```

Но когда я запрашиваю вывод команды с подсчетом строк в Linux, это выглядит так:

```
ps aux | wc -l # 179
```

В чем загвоздка? В мануале написано `Number of current processes`. Почему не совпадает с `aux`?
Теперь я немного запутался сколько же действительно текущих процессов в моей системе ...

Comment: Потому что процессами считаются и потоки тоже, а ps aux не отображает потоки.

Comment: @andreymal, понял, спасибо! и действительно если открыть top -H, то можно увидеть похожую цифру в колонке Threads

Answer (score 0):

Как заметил andreymal, это потому, что процессами считаются и потоки тоже, а `ps aux` не отображает потоки.